# Are these quoted sentences grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, synonyms

Are these quoted sentences grammatically correct?

> 1. That is why the businesses attach great importance to the
>      possibility of using ...
> 2. Many IT companies in their applications appreciates the benefits of
>      using cloud computing.

I am wondering if "businesses", "firms" and "companies" can be used interchangeably? Which one sounds better?

Comment: They're all "acceptable", but personally I would say ***companies*** is the most likely (and *firms* is the least likely) word native speakers would use in the context of your example usages. What native speakers would *never* do is include the word "the" as per the first example.

Comment: Two points: (1) "businesses" versus "firms" is an issue of regional dialect. Americans would most likely say "companies," but this is not true of all native speakers. (2) "the businesses" could be acceptable in certain contexts, depending on the preceding sentence.

Comment: You will also need to fix some subject and verb agreements in the second sentence. "Many IT companies (plural) appreciate (no "s") the benefits of using cloud computing in their applications".

Comment: "Firm" is used fairly often in British English. As @FumbleFingers said, "companies" is the best choice as it is the most widely understood.

Comment: Sentence 1. What businesses are you talking about?

Comment: @JMB: Toggling [**this NGram**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=many+firms+employ%2Cmany+companies+employ%2Cmany+businesses+employ&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmany%20firms%20employ%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmany%20companies%20employ%3B%2Cc0) between UK/US corpuses doesn't suggest that BrE is any more likely to use ***firm*** than AmE. But it might be worth noting that *for that particular search string*, ***businesses*** is in fact the least common choice.

Comment: @Fumble It might be a perception thing. "Firm" sounds formal to my ears; I usually hear it used with "law firm" or "accounting firm" and just about never with anything else. And I sometimes fall into the group of AmE speakers who often associate "formal" with "BrE", whether it's true or not. (I also watch the BBC a lot, so hopefully I'll eventually temper that with experience! ;)). But that might be where it's coming from. I've seen several times on ELL where AmE speakers think something sounds British, BrE speakers say "What are you talking about?", and I realize we're falling into that trap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would I be correct in completing your first "sentence" as follows:

> "That is why the businesses attach great importance to the possibility of using cloud computing"?

If your answer is yes, then my version of a completed sentence is just fine grammatically.

Your second sentence, however, needs a plural verb to go with a plural subject:

> "Many IT **companies** in their applications **appreciate** the benefits of using cloud computing."

Furthermore, "companies in their applications" I find troublesome. I recommend you word the sentence as follows:

> "Many IT companies appreciate the benefits of cloud computing."

That's why you want to say, yes?